# Terminal Server, Domain User can see folder and files saved in D: drive

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I want to set a Group Policy or something like that for old domain user and for new domain user, in a way that the domain user must not be able to see each other folder and files, if they login into same terminal Server

By default, Every Domain User login into Terminal Server, can open and read folder and files.I have two Drive C: and D:

User cannot see desktop of other User, but the folder saved in D: drive by User01 can be seen by User02 in read mode.

I want to deny this open and read folder rights for every domain user except the owner of the folder and files.

Can you help me? to figure it out.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `BUILTIN\Users` NTFS ACL from the path in question and add `Creator Owner` in its place.